# $A^{(−1)} = [a^{−1}_{i j} ]$ and, $rank A = 1$ and $A$ is positive semidefinite.Why does $A^{(−1)}$ positive semidefinite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A = [a_{i j }]\in M_n$ be positive semidefinite and suppose that each of its entries is nonzero.

Consider  $A^{(−1)} = [a^{−1}_{i j} ]$ and, $rank A = 1$.

Why is $A^{(−1)}$ 
positive
semidefinite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: An arbitrary $A$ of rank 1 is of the form $A = uv^T$ for non-zero vectors $u,v$. If $A$ is positive semidefinite, and has no zero entries (so that $A^{(-1)}$ exists), then you can assume $v = u$ (why?) and $u$ has no zero entries. Can you take it from there?

Comment: Please more guide.....